# How can i create a common node with which my other nodes can talk and do transaction with each other

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have created a fabric test network using first-network sample code. I which i have created 5 organizations segregated by collections to keep transactions between certain organization nodes private. But now i want to create a common node through which/by which every organization can do transaction and that particular transaction will data will be accessible by all the other organization node.

Profiles:

```
TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Global
        Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
        GlobalConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
                - *Org4
                - *Org5
                - *CommonGlobalBank
GlobalOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: GlobalConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
            - *Org3
            - *Org4
            - *Org5
            - *CommonGlobalBank
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

A common node through which/by which every organization can do transaction and that particular transaction will data will be accessible by all the other organization node.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking for "A Common Node" I think you should first investigate **channels** then **Private Data**.

You can create channels between various organisations e.g. Org1 & Org2, and Org1 & Org3, and then have a common channel which all organisations could be joined to.  The channel approach can get "busy" with lots of combinations of 2 and 3 channels!

Fabric now offers a Private Data feature whereby data can be shared by a subset of the organisations in the channel.

[This doc is a good place to start](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html) for Fabric, and does have a section comparing/contrasting the 2 approaches.